# Angular fails to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a working version of demo for a angular UI component

http://plnkr.co/edit/okm2AK50REbFeQ2ZTCeN?p=preview

You can see it loads a calendar in a panel

However taking this simple demo and moving it to our environment we are having some problems.  You can see our simple plunker here

http://plnkr.co/edit/Daf3E1yDeruHiD8qqJxr?p=preview

We are getting this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to:Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   app.splitter-panel due to:Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module kendo-directives due to:Error: [$injector:nomod]
>   Module 'kendo-directives' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

We know from the working demo that it is not an issue with the module not being available however the current inherited angular architecture within our system has an app.js and then the items.panel.js, the app.js tries to register the directive but it seems to be doing it incorrectly.

I guess what I am saying is the scaffolding in the second plunkr needs to be used, IE - we cant just change ng-app="app" to a smaller ng-app="demo" etc.  So we will need to make sure we can get it to work using the app.js and the items.panel.js as the controller

I believe the app.js is not loading something correctly

```
(function () {

    angular.module('app.splitter-panel', ['kendo-directives']);


    angular.module('app', [
    'app.splitter-panel'
    ]);
})();
```

however let me know what would need to be fixed

Comment: really not hard to figure out. The error tells you where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy and paste the following inside your `app.js`

```
angular.module('app.splitter-panel', ['kendo.directives']);

angular.module('app', ['app.splitter-panel']);
```

You misspelled `kendo.directives` you wrote `kendo-directives` instead